# Understanding jquery event toggling

Tags: jquery

I am slowly getting familiar to Javascript and now I have a really easy question
In case my terminology is not on the spot, please ask and/or correct me

How can I have these two (or more) behaviors in the same script (file).

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $container = $('div.fillField'),
        divs = $("div.onethird").get().sort(function(){ 
                return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
            }).slice(0,3),
            $clonedDivs = $(divs).clone();
        $container.html('');
        $clonedDivs.each(function( index ) {
            $container.append(this);
            if (index % 3 == 0) {
              $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
            } else {
              $(this).css("margin-left", "2%");
            }
        });

        $clonedDivs.show();

        //break & next command

        var $container = $('div.fillField'),
            divs = $("li.onethirdAll").get().sort(function(){ 
                return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
            }),
            $clonedDivs = $(divs).clone();
        $container.html('');
        $clonedDivs.each(function( index ) {
            $container.append(this);
           });
        $clonedDivs.show();
    });
```

Separately they work fine but to have them together it seems only the lastone is being executed

Comment: What do you mean by "separately"?

Comment: It's jQuery - not JS, please change the title & tag.

Comment: I see where you're going with this.... you want a toggle switch effect... work with the answer below to get your events to react to their specific state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines of code in your second block:

```
var $container = $('div.fillField');
$container.html('');
```

are clearing what you did in your first block so that `div.fillField` is empty again (wiping out what you just added to it in the first part of your code).

It's not completely clear what you want the behavior to be, but perhaps you just want to append new content onto the container and not clear it in the second block.

Comment: As jfriend00 pointed out $container.html('') is clearing the action of first block of your code. I apologize for not seeing that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know whatever you are doing separately is fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var $container = $('div.fillField'),
        divs = $("div.onethird").get().sort(function(){ 
                return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
            }).slice(0,3),
            $clonedDivs = $(divs).clone();
        $container.html('');
        $clonedDivs.each(function( index ) {  //this function will be called asynchronously and is using $clonedDivs and $container 
            $container.append(this);
            if (index % 3 == 0) {
              $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
            } else {
              $(this).css("margin-left", "2%");
            }
        });

        $clonedDivs.show();

        //break & next command

        //use different variables
        var $container2 = $('div.fillField');

        var divs2 = $("li.onethirdAll").get().sort(function(){ 
            return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
        });

        var $clonedDivs2 = $(divs2).clone();
        $container2.html('');
        $clonedDivs2.each(function( index ) {
            $container2.append(this);
        });
        $clonedDivs2.show();
    });
```

please read about comma operator and variable declaration in javascript. also read about closures.

if you just wish to isolate two different code snippets, use anonymous function.

```
(function(){
   //first snippet - behaviour if you may
})();

(function(){
   //second
})();
```

Comment: i used 2 suffix just to show you correlation. in actual code use some meaningful names.

Comment: `$container2.html('');` is clearing the action of the first block of code.  Changing the variable names doesn't solve that.

Comment: the intent of the OP isnt actually clear. thats why i added at the top "Assuming you know whatever you are doing separately is fine." and simply tried to solve the isolation part of the problem.

Comment: What do you think you solved?  In this case, there's no problem with reusing variable names.  The issue is that the second block of code is wiping out what the first block of code did and that's why they don't work when both used.

Comment: i just tried to give him a direction to look for. Does the code makes sense at all? appending li and div elements to same division? just avoiding clearing the container will help? i can see now that my answer isn't helping much. or probably none at all. bye all means downvote.